# GAE/P: Implementing Exponential backoff for RPC calls

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rpc

I know that exponential backoff is a good thing when RPC calls fail.  So far in my GAE/P app I have implemented exponential backoff by using the task queue:

```
deferred.defer(function_that_makes_RPC_call)
```

If the function that does the RPC call raises an exception, then the exponential backoff of the task queue takes care of it, and I don't have to worry about it.

A problem, however, is that deferred.defer is itself an RPC call that can fail!  I sometimes get this error:

> DeadlineExceededError: The API call taskqueue.BulkAdd() took too long
>   to respond and was cancelled.

So it seems I can no longer be lazy and have to implement my own exponential backoff. :(

I'm thinking to put a wrapper around `deferred.defer` that implements exponential backoff using [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff), like this:

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      (exception1, exception2, ...),
                      max_tries=8)
def defer_wrapper(function_that_makes_RPC_call):
    deferred.defer(function_that_makes_RPC_call)
```

Here, the decorator implements the backoff where a retry happens when one of the enumerated exceptions (e.g., exception1, exception2, ...) is raised.

A couple questions about this:

1. Is this a good solution for implementing exponential backoff?
2. What exceptions do I need to list?  Anything other than DeadlineExceededError?

I know it is somewhat redundant to have my own exponential backoff and then submit to a task queue, but I'm thinking that `deferred.defer` should fail more rarely than other RPC calls and I'd like to respond to the request ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particular for the `DeadlineExceededError` in attempts to enqueue a deferred task I'd just do back2back retries instead of using an exponential backoff - the attempts will be spaced 5s apart due to the deadline interval expiration itself anyways, which gives a max of 12 retries before the request itself hits its deadline.

Probably a good idea for other types of failures, though.

Comment: I think this DeadlineExceededError is specific for API calls and is 5 seconds as opposed to the request DeadlineExceededError of 60 seconds.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Comment: Ah, *that* DeadlineExceededError? Yes, you're right.